# Weatherkit data how to improve app launch?

Tags: swift, swiftui, weatherkit

I am making a weather app with the new Apple weatherKit.
I want to improve the launch of the application because sometimes it crashes.
So I would like at launch the data to be refreshed (loaded) and when the application is in the background, the data is refreshed every 30 min.
here is the swift file i am trying to edit.

thank you

```
    @main
struct PlaneWXApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase

    let weatherModel: WeatherModel
    
    @StateObject var launchScreeenManager = LaunchScreenManager()

    init() {
        self.weatherModel = WeatherModel()

        weatherModel.refresh()
    }
    @State private var selection = 3

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack{
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    alertView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(1)
                    todayView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(2)
                    homeView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(3)
                    forecastView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(4)

                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                .onAppear
                {
                    DispatchQueue
                        .main
                        .asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                            launchScreeenManager.dismiss()
                        }
                    
                    UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
                    UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
                }
                
                if launchScreeenManager.state != .completed{
                    LaunchScreenView()
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(launchScreeenManager)
        }
        .onChange(of: phase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
            case .background: scheduleAppRefresh()
            default: break
            }
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("myapprefresh")) {
            await weatherModel.refresh()
        }
    }
}

func scheduleAppRefresh() {
    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "myapprefresh")
    request.earliestBeginDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600)
    try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
}
```

WeatherModel:

```
@MainActor
```

class WeatherModel: ObservableObject {
let locationProvider = LocationProvider()

```
@Published var temperature: String?
@Published var minTemperature: String?
@Published var maxTemperature: String?

@Published var feelTemperature: String?
@Published var feelTemperatureDescription: String?
@Published var dewPoint: String?

@Published var alerts: [WeatherAlertInfo] = []

@Published var wind: [Wind] = []


func refresh() {
    Task {
        await getAddress()
        await getWeather()
    }
}

private func getAddress() async{

    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    currentLocation = locManager.location
    
    if let currentLocation {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                  longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        
        locationProvider.getPlace(for: location) { plsmark in
            guard let placemark = plsmark else { return }
            if let city = placemark.locality,
               let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
                self.cityName = "\(city), \(state)"
            } else if let city = placemark.locality, let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
                self.cityName = "\(city) \(state)"
            } else {
                self.cityName = "Address Unknown"
            }
        }
    }
 }
          
private func getWeather() async {
    let weatherService = WeatherService()
            
    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    currentLocation = locManager.location
    
    let weather: Weather?
    
    if let currentLocation {
        let coordinate = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                    ,longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        weather = try? await weatherService.weather(for: coordinate)
    } else {
        weather = nil
    }

    var todayForecast: DayWeather? {
       weather?.dailyForecast.first{Calendar.current.isDateInToday($0.date) }
    }

    minTemperature = todayForecast?.lowTemperature.formatted()
    maxTemperature = todayForecast?.highTemperature.formatted()
```

Location provider

```
private func getAddress() async{

        let locManager = CLLocationManager()
        var currentLocation: CLLocation!
        currentLocation = locManager.location
        
        if let currentLocation {
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                      longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            
            locationProvider.getPlace(for: location) { plsmark in
                guard let placemark = plsmark else { return }
                if let city = placemark.locality,
                   let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
                    self.cityName = "\(city), \(state)"
                } else if let city = placemark.locality, let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
                    self.cityName = "\(city) \(state)"
                } else {
                    self.cityName = "Address Unknown"
                }
            }
        }
     }
              
    private func getWeather() async {
        let weatherService = WeatherService()
                
        let locManager = CLLocationManager()
        var currentLocation: CLLocation!
        currentLocation = locManager.location
        
        let weather: Weather?
        
        if let currentLocation {
            let coordinate = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                        ,longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            weather = try? await weatherService.weather(for: coordinate)
        } else {
            weather = nil
        }
}


public func getPlace(for location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark?) -> Void) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("=====> Error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
            print("=====> Error placemark is nil")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(placemark)
    }
}
```

Launch process

```
@main
struct PlaneWXApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var phase
    @StateObject var model = WeatherModel()

    @StateObject var launchScreeenManager = LaunchScreenManager()

    @State private var selection = 3

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack{
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    alertView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(1)
                    todayView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(2)
                    homeView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(3)
                    forecastView(weatherModel: weatherModel).tag(4)

                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                .onAppear
                {
                    DispatchQueue
                        .main
                        .asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                            launchScreeenManager.dismiss()
                        }
                    
                    UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
                    UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
                }
                
                if launchScreeenManager.state != .completed{
                    LaunchScreenView()
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(launchScreeenManager)
        }
        .onChange(of: phase) { newPhase in
            switch newPhase {
            case .background: scheduleAppRefresh()
            default: break
            }
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("myapprefresh")) {
            await model.getWeather()
        }
    }
}

func scheduleAppRefresh() {
    let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "myapprefresh")
    request.earliestBeginDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600)
    try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre]. Please add `WeatherModel` and `LaunchScreenManager`. Also, what error do you get?

Comment: I put the modelWeather. thanks

Comment: The message points to an error while starting a thread. What caught my eye is your faulty usage of `let weatherModel: WeatherModel`. This should be a `@StateObject`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so can you help me please on that with a correct code

Comment: You are mixing completion handlers with async await, the get address method is not compatible with the new concurrency

Comment: The problem is that `currentLocation` is created as implicit unwrapped optional and doesn't have a value when being accessed because retrieving the current location is asynchronous. And it's a terrible practice to declare all `@Published` properties carelessly optional. Don't do that. I recommend to `@publish` a state enum with cases  `.idle`, `.loading` and `.loaded(Weather)`) – all non-optional – and show an appropriate view to the user.

Comment: PS: The solution is to make `getAddress` also `async` and swap the lines `getAddress` and `getWeather`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just took your advice. How can I do a background refresh every 30 min?

Comment: I edit the question, with my background Task, is ok for you ??

Comment: No, just adding the `async` keyword doesn't change anything. The crucial line is `currentLocation = locManager.location`. You have to tell `CLLocationManager` to request the current location. This is asynchronous, too. To adopt `async/await` you need a `Continuation` because `CLLocationManager` is delegate based and doesn't provide an `async/await` API. A background fetch can be accomplished with a timer, but I would prefer to refresh the data on demand, this means when the app becomes active.

Comment: I don't understand, can you show me a code to better understand? thank you

Comment: Please show the code of `LocationProvider`

Comment: I add the location provider in the topic, thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of `getAddress` I need the implementation of the `getPlace` method.

Answer (score 0):

The code cannot work because you have to ask `CLLocationManager` to get the current location asynchronously.

This is a basic implementation of a location manager to get the current location and the places for a location `async/await` compliant.

```
import CoreLocation

@MainActor
class LocationManager : NSObject {
   
    private var continuation : CheckedContinuation<CLLocation, Error>?
    private let locationManager : CLLocationManager
   
    public override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    
    public func currentLocation() async throws -> CLLocation {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    public func getPlaces(for location: CLLocation) async throws -> [CLPlacemark] {
        try await CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: nil)
    }
}

extension LocationManager : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.continuation?.resume(returning: locations.last!)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

`WeatherModel` can be reduced to the following, rather than having a lot of optional `@Published` properties there are only two (non-optional), a `state` enum which indicates several phases and the `cityName`

```
@MainActor
class WeatherModel: ObservableObject {

    enum LoadingState {
        case idle, loading, loaded(CurrentWeather, DayWeather), failed(Error)
    }
    
    let service = WeatherService()

    @Published var state = LoadingState.idle
    @Published var cityName = "" 

    func getWeather() async {
        state = .loading
        let manager = LocationManager()
        do {
            let location = try await manager.currentLocation()
            let weather = try await service.weather(for: location)
            let places = try await manager.getPlaces(for: location)
            let today = weather.dailyForecast.first{ Calendar.current.isDateInToday($0.date) }!
            state = .loaded(weather.currentWeather, today)
            guard let placemark = places.first else { return }
            if let city = placemark.locality,
               let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
                self.cityName = "\(city), \(state)"
            } else if let city = placemark.locality {
                self.cityName = city
            } else {
                self.cityName = "Address Unknown"
            }
        } catch {
            state = .failed(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the view create an instance of `WeatherModel` and switch on the `state`. Add your views in the `loaded` and `failed` states.

```
import WeatherKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = WeatherModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            switch model.state {
                case .idle: EmptyView()
                case .loading: ProgressView()
                case .loaded(let currentWeather, let today): // show weather data
                case .failed(let error): // show error 
        }
        .task {
            await model.getWeather()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but How can I load data from weatherModel (temperature, wind, ...)

Comment: All information is in `currentWeather` and `today`. Print the instances to see what they contain. Or read the documentation.

Comment: Ok And I don't understand you last code. Where can I replace your code in my project ? I've a tabview when I launch the app.

Comment: I put the launch process code in the topic. thanks

Comment: You can put the code in any `body` of a `view`. And again, you should prefer refreshing the data on demand over an interval.

Comment: I have lots of errors since the last changes and I'm stuck, do you accept that I send you the files elsewhere than here because I can't do it and it's an important project for me. Thank you for your help

Comment: how can I use weather values ? model.pressure?.doubleValue() ?? 0 doesn't work

Comment: As mentioned in your previous question `pressure`, `temperature` etc are `Measurement` types. They are **not** a string. To get the Double value call `value`.

Comment: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'task'