# Unable to get user's location using CLLocationManager

Tags: swiftui, cllocation, weatherkit

I am having an issue when trying to request the user's location using CLLocationManager. When running my app, the Console gives this error: `[WeatherDataService] Response did not contain requested dataset: .appLocationConfig. Returning default value: AppLocationConfig(reportAnIssue: ReportIssueLocationConfig(position: beforeFooter, minDaysSinceInteraction: 0), expireTime: 2023-01-23 07:30:06 +0000`.

I tried looking up some tutorials on requesting the user's location using CLLocationManager but none of them worked.

Here is my LocationManager class and extension:

```swift
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let location = locations.last, currentLocation == nil else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.currentLocation = location
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code inside my VStack:

```swift
VStack{
    if let weather {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Singapore")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            VStack {
                Text("Condition: \(weather.currentWeather.condition.rawValue)")
                    .font(.title2)
                Text("Temperature: \(weather.currentWeather.temperature.formatted())")
                    .font(.title2)
                Text("Feels like: \(weather.currentWeather.apparentTemperature.formatted())")
                    .font(.title2)
//              Text("Min: \() Max: \()")
//                  .font(.title)
            }
        }
        Text("Today, \(weather.currentWeather.date.formatted())")
                        .font(.subheadline)
    }
                
    ScrollView(.vertical){
        VStack{
            HourlyForcastView(hourWeatherList: hourlyWeatherData, hourlyWeatherData: hourlyWeatherData)
            TenDayForcastView(dayWeatherList: weather.dailyForecast.forecast)
                        
            HStack{
                // Humidity
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "humidity")
                        .font(.system(size: 65))
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    let humidity = (weather.currentWeather.humidity * 100)
                    Text("HUMIDITY")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("\(humidity.formatted())%")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                    .frame(width: 155)
                    .padding()
                    .background(content: {Color.blue})
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                            
                // Pressure
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                    let pressure = (weather.currentWeather.pressure)
                        Text("PRESSURE")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("\(pressure.formatted())")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                    .frame(width: 155)
                    .padding()
                    .background(content: {Color.blue})
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                        }
                        
                HStack{
                    // Dew Point
                    VStack{
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "drop")
                                .font(.system(size: 56.5))
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            Image(systemName: "drop")
                                .font(.system(size: 56.5))
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        }
                        let dewPoint = (weather.currentWeather.dewPoint)
                        Text("DEW POINT")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("\(dewPoint.formatted())")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                    .frame(width: 155)
                    .padding()
                    .background(content: {Color.blue})
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                            
                // UV Index
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "sun.max")
                        .font(.system(size: 53))
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    let uvIndex = (weather.currentWeather.uvIndex)
                    Text("UV INDEX")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("\(uvIndex.value) - \(uvIndex.category.rawValue)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                            .frame(width: 155)
                            .padding()
                            .background(content: {Color.blue})
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                            
                        }
                        HStack{
                            // Wind Speed
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: "wind")
                                    .font(.system(size: 53))
                                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                let windSpeed = (weather.currentWeather.wind)
                                Text("WIND SPEED")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                Text("\(windSpeed.speed.formatted())")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 155)
                            .padding()
                            .background(content: {Color.blue})
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                            
                            // Wind Direction
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: "wind")
                                    .font(.system(size: 53))
                                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                let windSpeed = (weather.currentWeather.wind)
                                Text("WIND DIRECTION")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                Text("\(windSpeed.compassDirection.rawValue)")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 155)
                            .padding()
                            .background(content: {Color.blue})
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                        }
                        HStack{
                            // Visibility
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: "mountain.2")
                                    .font(.system(size: 53))
                                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                let visibility = (weather.currentWeather.visibility)
                                Text("VISIBILITY")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                Text("\(visibility.formatted())")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 155)
                            .padding()
                            .background(content: {Color.blue})
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: .continuous))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I also add a .task to my VStack so the weather data will only show up when the user's location has been retrieved:

```swift
} // This is where the VStack ends.
    .padding()
    .task(id: locationManager.currentLocation) {
        do {
//          if let location = locationManager.currentLocation {
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: 1.30437, longitude: 103.82458)
                self.weather =  try await weatherService.weather(for: location)
//          }
        } catch {
            print(error)
          }
           
        }
```

Comment: The error is not related to `LocationManager`. Apart from that Apple highly recommends [*Important: Always implement the methods for handling any potential failures in addition to the methods for receiving location-related data.*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate) And the commented line `if let location = locationManager.currentLocation` is always `nil` the first time because retrieving the location is asynchronous.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192581/weatherkit-data-how-to-improve-app-launch/75199532?noredirect=1#comment132705598_75199532) for a `async/await` version to get the current location.

Comment: Hi @vadian. When I replace my LocationManager Class and Extension, my VStack throws me an error saying `Type '() async throws -> CLLocation' cannot conform to 'Equatable'`. I will edit my question to show what is in the VStack

Comment: The `task` modifier must be on the top level of the view. I even recommend to use a view model.

Comment: You don’t want your task id based on location. You will get thousands of calls very quickly, do some math, get the distance between the location you last used and the newest one.

Comment: @vadian what do you mean by the `task` modifier should be on the top level of the view?

Comment: I mean the top level of the `body` of the view, as a modifier of the first `Navigation/H/V/Z/Stack` or `Group`.